# Ошибка при работе PhantomJS с Selenium Python

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, phantomjs

Мне нужно распарить страницу подписок в истаграме, для этого использую selenium с phantomjs. PhantomJS нужен как для работы в фоновом режиме. Изначально делал с Chrome. С Chrome всё работало отлично, а вот с PhantomJS выдается ошибка. В чем может быть проблема?

P.S. работу Chrome в фоновом режиме не предлагайте, так как нужен именно PhantomJS.
P.S.S Не забудьте внести свой логин и пароль в код от Инстаграма

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/urgantcom/following/")

login = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
login.send_keys('your-user-name')

password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys('your-password')

enter = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_qv64e      ')
enter.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

profile_info = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_t98z6 ')
following = profile_info[2]
following.click()

following_quantity = int(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_fd86t ')[2].text)

following_list = []
while int(len(following_list)) != following_quantity:
    el = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='_6e4x5']")[-1]
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", el)
    following_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='_6e4x5']")

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

profile_users = soup.find_all('div', class_='_2nunc')

for profile_user in profile_users:
    inst_username = profile_user.find('a', class_='_2g7d5').text
    print(inst_username)
```

Вот какую выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/parser/script.py", line 29, in <module>
    following = profile_info[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: «так как нужен именно PhantomJS» — почему?

Comment: И какая ошибка выдаётся-то?

Comment: PhantomJS нужен для того, чтобы я мог добавить этот код на сайт, который на Heroku

Comment: Он тупо не находит элементы, хотя через Chrome всё ок, все находит

Comment: Какие элементы? Приведите полный текст ошибки в вопросе

Comment: Добавил, какую ошибку выводит

Comment: Я бы посоветовал вам искать элементы Xpath'ом а не class_name'ом. Запишите XPath так, что-бы он возвращал вам только тот элемент, на который вам нужно нажать. Ну и в таких ситуациях было-бы неплохо делать скриншот страницы перед поиском элемента, что-бы наглядно видеть, что пытаемся искать